# document goes out of full screen when new url

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I've written the following code segment to get the window to fullscreen.

```
docElm.requestFullscreen();
```

When I open a url to open in the same window, the new url makes the window go out of fulscreen. I use the following to go to the next url,

```
window.location.assign("/settings");
```

How can I fix this issue and make the window stay fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue and is to be expected.

There are two reasons for this:

### Technical

The document or one of its element which the full-screen mode is bound to is no longer available or valid when navigating to a new site. The document or element is unreferenced and browser will revert to normal mode.

Full-screen mode in browsers are not actual full-screen modes such as you see in for instance ActiveX / video players. They are simply element overlays that are shown at the full size of the screen (eg. by CSS rules defined internally by the browser). This creates dependency on the current DOM and document.

The new site does not necessary have the same elements in the same order etc. and from a browser perspective is an entirely new DOM tree.

### Security

Full-screen mode is permitted for the current url only and must be permitted by the user for each site.

Lets say the user allow current site but not next site - if your solution could direct the user to the second site in full-screen mode your solution would violate the user's preference.

Under the current [Fullscreen API document you can find under section 4.](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#api) one of the criterias to establish full-screen mode:

> There is a previously-established user preference, security risk, or
>   platform limitation.

This first part of the criteria is not fulfilled when the browser navigate to a new url without the user permitting full-screen mode for it.

This of course implies the newly navigated site won't show in full-screen mode until permitted.

This is [important because](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#security-and-privacy-considerations):

> User agents should ensure, e.g. by means of an overlay, that the end
>   user is aware something is displayed fullscreen. User agents should
>   provide a means of exiting fullscreen that always works and advertise
>   this to the user. This is to prevent a site from spoofing the end user
>   by recreating the user agent or even operating system environment when
>   fullscreen. See also the definition of requestFullscreen().
>
> To prevent embedded content from going fullscreen only embedded
>   content specifically allowed via the allowfullscreen attribute of the
>   HTML iframe element will be able to go fullscreen. This prevents
>   untrusted content from going fullscreen.

There are security issues involved which is why browsers won't allow you to continue full-screen mode when changing url.

The [Fullscreen API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) has currently experimental status.

### Possible workarounds

You can serve content through AJAX to update the page.

If your intention is to allow an user to browse various sites in full-screen mode you will need to solve this at browser level, ie. create an application which in one way or another implements an engine like .Net WebBrowser for IE or WebKit - or - forking an existing WebKit browser and override this behavior at source level.

Then you can allow browsing to happen in full-screen mode at will.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I'm actually developing a web application using java + spring. I am trying to make the whole application use in full screen.

Comment: No problem @DimalChandrasiri. I am not familiar with java+spring so I can't help there but, I think AJAX might be the way to go (without knowing of course what your application do).